# Control Over fopen Timeout When Opening Via FTP

Tags: php, ftp

I realize that there are other more straightforward ways to conduct FTP.  However, I have a specific need to be able to use fopen on a file via FTP.  The following code works just great:

```
$FTP="ftp://$FTPUser:$FTPPass@$FTPHost/$file_dest";
$fp=fopen($FTP, 'w');
```

The problem is when the path of the $file_dest is invalid.  For example if $file_dest="1/2/3/test.txt".

If the 1, 2, or 3 folders do not exist, then it takes 90 seconds for the fopen to fail.

How can I reduce this timeout?

Comment: I'm out of votes to close as duplicate. The method shown in this duplicate should apply 1:1: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2511225/how-to-get-fopen-to-timeout-properly

Comment: That other question is for fopen on http, I tried it and it doesn't seem to be working for ftp.

Answer (score 0):

I would have suggested [creating](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php) a [stream context](http://www.php.net/manual/en/context.ftp.php), but as you say, there seems to be no `timeout` option for the FTP protocol there.

Try whether the `default_socket_timeout` option as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881816/php-fopen-function-timed-out) applies to FTP operations - I'm not entirely sure.

If that doesn't work out, I'm not sure whether you don't have to resort to the [proper FTP functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-connect.php), which definitely allow for setting a timeout.

Comment: The webhost server that I'm ftping from doesn't have disk io privlidges, so I can't read from the disk.  I have access only to the filecontents posted via http.  ftp_put fails because the source content is a file, not a string.  Lots of web-hosts deny file io (yet fully support ftp!), so I need to cover this case.

Comment: @Joshua how about using a data wrapper as a file resource and reading from that? http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.data.php